# Project Euler #82 - path sum: three ways

Tags: python, project-euler, matrix, dynamic-programming

[Project Euler problem 82](http://projecteuler.net/problem=82) asks:

[image]

Here's my solution:

```
def main():    
    matrix = [
        [131, 673, 234, 103,  18],
        [201,  96, 342, 965, 150],
        [630, 803, 746, 422, 111],
        [537, 699, 497, 121, 956],
        [805, 732, 524,  37, 331]
    ]

    size = len(matrix)
    best = [matrix[row][0] for row in range(size)]

    for col in range(1, size):
        column = [matrix[row][col] for row in range(size)]
        tmp = column[:]

        for i in range(size):
            column[i] += best[i] # right

            for j in range(0, i): # up
                if sum([best[j]]+tmp[j:i+1]) < column[i]:
                    column[i] = sum([best[j]]+tmp[j:i+1])

            for k in range(i, size): # bottom
                if sum([best[k]] +tmp[i:k+1]) < column[i]:
                    column[i] = sum([best[k]] +tmp[i:k+1])

        best = column
        #print(best)

    return min(best)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

Please advise how it can be improved.

Comment: [Here's a interesting read on #82](http://csjobinterview.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/project-euler-problem-82/) if you haven't seen it yet

Comment: @megawac This solution uses the same strategy described in the article, except that it's already more eloquent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the Project Euler challenge, you'll have to handle a large matrix from a file.  Therefore, your function should accept the matrix as a parameter.

You used `size` to represent both the number of rows and the number of columns.  I would use two variables to avoid hard-coding the assumption that the input is a square matrix.

Your dynamic programming algorithm is sound.  I would use the `min()` function to avoid finding the minimum by iteration.  Also, setting `best` all at once instead of mutating the elements of `column` avoids having to copy `column` into a temporary variable.

```
def euler82(matrix):
    nrows, ncols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    best = [matrix[row][0] for row in range(nrows)]

    for col in range(1, ncols):
        column = [matrix[row][col] for row in range(nrows)]

        best = [
            # The cost of each cell, plus...
            column[row] +

            # the cost of the cheapest approach to it
            min([
                best[prev_row] + sum(column[prev_row:row:(1 if prev_row <= row else -1)])
                for prev_row in range(nrows)
            ])
            for row in range(nrows)
        ]

        #print(best)

    return min(best)
```